# Python error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python

Please someone help

I wrote this code:

```
namefile = open("name_of_user.txt", "w")
namefile = ()
if (namefile) == ():
  name = input("Username:")
  namefile.write(name)
  namefile.close()

password = input("Create a password: ")
passwordfile = open("passworduser.txt", "w")
passwordfile.write(password)
passwordfile.close()
```

and it says this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/HU6MLICK/Desktop/Python/UCode/UCode_1.1-Beta.py", line 6, in <module>
    namefile.write(name)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: What do you think `namefile = ()` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

All is fine, just remove namefile = () because it converts your file into a turple

```
namefile = open("name_of_user.txt", "w")
    #namefile = ()
    if (namefile) == ():
      name = input("Username:")
      namefile.write(name)
      namefile.close()
    
    password = input("Create a password: ")
    passwordfile = open("passworduser.txt", "w")
    passwordfile.write(password)
    passwordfile.close()
```

Comment: The cause of the error is that you opened a .txt file in a write mode, then after you converted it into a tuple using filename = ().

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to check by `if (namefile) == ():` ?
the function `open()` in mode `w`, open a file for writing and creates a new file if it does not exist, so you don't need to check if the file exists or not.
If you want to check if the file is empty, you can do that by:

```
import os
namefile = open("name_of_user.txt", "w")   
if os.path.getsize("name_of_user.txt") == 0:
  name = input("Username:")
  namefile.write(name)
namefile.close()
```